# Can every non-hemi uniform polytope tile hyperbolic space?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, polytopes

Can every uniform polytope which is not a hemipolytope tile hyperbolic space on its own?

Comment: Could you please define *hemipolytope*? Thanks.

Comment: A hemipolytope is a polytope whose circumcenter lies on at least one of its facets.

Comment: Must the tile be compact? Or do you allow ideal (or hyper-ideal) vertices?

Comment: Paracompact and noncompact tilings are fine.

Comment: I believe all the convex uniform polyhedra do.